# Count deleted records, returns 0

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I perform a `DELETE` in my table from my servlet by calling a method `action.deleteBox(box);` which executes the delete function
**deleteBox method**

```
Connection c = null;
PreparedStatement stm = null;
sq = "DELETE FROM BOXES WHERE ...";

try {       
    Class.forName(typeDB);
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);    
    stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
    //...
    stm.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {             
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
        System.out.println("my stm is closed : " + stm.isClosed());
        if (stm != null)
                    stm.close();
        if (c != null)
                    c.close();
}
```

the delete is executed fine. Then I want to check how many records were deleted from the previous delete: So I call this method:

```
public int countDeletesRecords() 
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    sq = "SELECT changes() as \"deletedRows\" ";
    int deletedRows=-1;

    try {       
        Class.forName(typeDB);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);    
        stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);       
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            deletedRows = rs.getInt("deletedRows");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {             
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.out.println("my stm is closed : " + stm.isClosed());
        if (stm != null)
            stm.close();
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
    } 

    return deletedRows; //I get 0..
}
```

and I get 0, while 1 records where deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) says:

> This function returns the number of rows modified, inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement on the database connection

You are creating a new database connection in which no DELETE statement was ever executed.

Answer (score 3):

While this does not directly answer the question an alternative, simpler, approach would capture the return value of [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--), that returns the number of affected (in this case, deleted) rows:

```
final int deletedRowCount = stm.executeUpdate();
```